# Is there a fast of silence in Islam?

Tags: sharia, ramadan, sawm

I have been wondering, can we Muslims keep silence for one or more day as a way of fasting? as it is in many traditions and religions to gain self-control and inner peace. 
I don't mean we do that instead of usual Ramadan fasts, but do it in any time that we feel it necessary or as an extra self-control way.

Comment: How do we recite Qur'an if we are silent? A better suggestion would be remember Allah using our tongue more often and leave off useless speech.

Comment: well I would start reading Qur'an after that the fast is ended, like at the end of the day.

Comment: the thing is I heard it's haram? is it, really?

Comment: What is haraam?

Comment: haraam means forbidden

Comment: I know that. Thanks. But, I am asking "what" you heard is haraam? Silence or speaking?

Comment: Oh! Sorry :). I heard that Fast of silence is Haraam. But it makes no sense to me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fast of silence has no origin in Islam and Prophet Muhammad (saww) was never seen to do that. So keeping silence with the intention of fasting seems to be a kind of bidah and thus Haraam in Islam.

The following quote from [Imam Ali ibn al-Husayn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_ibn_al-Husayn_Zayn_al-%27Abidin) (as) can certify this claim:

> صوم الصمت حرامٌ
>
> Fast of silence is Haraam.
>
> [Reference: [Wasa'il al-Shiʿa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Was%C4%81%27il_al-Sh%C4%AB%CA%BFa), volume 7, page 390]

However, you are free to keep silence with any other intention. But based on this hadith from Prophet Muhammad (saww) it's better not to do it from day to night:

> عن علي بن ابراهيم عن ابيه عن ابن ابي عمير عن منصور بن حازم عن ابي عبدالله جعفر بن محمد عليه السلام قال: قال رسول الله صلي الله عليه و آله:
>   **لا صمت یوماً إلی اللیل**
>
> Do not silence day to night.

You should also note that the verse [19:26](http://quran.com/19/26) which states that Hazrat Maryam (as) had vowed the fast of silence to Allah, has nothing to do with Islamic sharia.

Comment: but why? :( It's not against anything or any other rules. I don't want to commit sins but I really feel it could help me.

Comment: @Peggy Well, if you feel it's that much helpful you can do it. Just don't intend to fast. Do it for yourself. But if I were you I'd have kept silence except for mentioning and praising Allah.

Comment: yes that's the whole idea

Answer (score 0):

Fasting is an act of worship and the intention of worship is to please God and gain his nearness and consciousness. Had fasting of silence been a way to achieve that, Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) must have told us about this kind of worship. As there is no such thing reported from him, this is not a worship. Linking a label of "fast" is not appropriate for it.

There is no harm in doing such thing if it improves your self control. Just don't link it to religion.